# dynamic pdf Implementation in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added blank pdf file in my ci project and wants to edit it dynamically.
I mean I have created some blank text fields in my pdf and wants to fill the value with ci code. please answer me is this possible or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi surbhi, check this link https://www.pdfzorro.com/EDIT/api_anleitung.php

Comment: no, not like this. I want something like after register the details of user will edit on pdf file.

Comment: Surbhi tum direct pdf file me edit nhi kar sakti

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing an existing PDF you should use a PHP/PDF generator that creates a PDF from scratch and uses your supplied data in the PDF that gets created.

There are lots of open source libraries out there that can do this for you. Just search 'PHP PDF' but here is an example of one I've used with great success and it's easy to use:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: yeah I have already tried this. but I need to edit pdf rather than html.
If there is any solution then please help me

Comment: I don't see why you need the user to edit the PDF live in the browser? 
If you get the user to add their details in a web form you can then use that input to generate the PDF. Editing a PDF in the browser is probably outside of the scope of Codeigniter/open source library.

Comment: actually, pdf format is already given and process is like that when user fill their details in html form then blank pdf will get updated by their details and after that I have to send this pdf to their email id. so I need some code that will direct insert value in pdf